# How can i reuse a gherkin scenario in another one

Tags: java, selenium, gherkin

I want to use the Login scenario in another scenario (Landing) so that I can prevent redundancy,
Actually I don't know if I can do this through heritage :

```
                              _ FormPage0
LoginPage --> LandingPage -->|_ 
                                FormPage1
```

how can I do it?

**login.feature**

```
@login
@config-boost-config.yml

Feature: Login/Logout in Boost
  @login-01
  Scenario Outline: <ID_Iteration> - login scenario
    Given user logged with <login> <password>
    Examples:
  ## ${boost.login}
```

**loginStepDefinition.java**

```java
public class LoginStepDefinition extends BaseStepDefinition {

    private LoginPage loginPage;    
    @Before
    public void setup(Scenario scenario) throws MalformedURLException, TestingException {
        super.setup(scenario);
        this.loginPage = new LoginPage(this.scenarioContext);
    }  
    @Given("^user logged with (.+) (.+)$")
    public void user_logged_with(String login, String password) throws Throwable {
        this.loginPage.login(login, password);
    }
    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        super.tearDown();
    }
}
```

**landing.feature**

```
@landing
@config-boost-config.yml

Feature: landing
  @landing-01
  Scenario Outline: <ID_Iteration> - landing scenario
    When user choose a brand
    And user choose a bu

    Examples:
  ## ${boost.landing}
```

**landingStepDefinition.java**

```java
public class LandingStepDefinition extends BaseStepDefinition {

    private LandingPage landingPage;
    @Before
    public void setup(Scenario scenario) throws MalformedURLException, TestingException {
        super.setup(scenario);
        this.landingPage = new LandingPage(this.scenarioContext);
    }
    @When("^user choose a brand$")
    public void user_choose_a_brand() throws Throwable {
        landingPage.chooseBrand();
    }
    @When("^user choose a bu$")
    public void user_choose_a_bu() throws Throwable {
        landingPage.chooseBU();
    }
    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        super.tearDown();
    }
}
```

**PS:** i'm using a framework based on Selenium

Answer (score 0):

If logging in is a prerequisite for visiting the landing then, then there is nothing wrong with including a step to log in the user in each scenario.

It is one step and not much to copy and paste. I wouldn't worry about it. If you really, really wanted to, modify the step definition for `When user choose a brand` to log the user in first. Inject your LoginPage model into the LandingStepDefinition class. The `login` method should return a page model representing the page that loads after logging in. That page model should have public methods allowing the user to navigate to other pages. Those methods return page models for those pages. Just keep calling methods on page models until you are on the landing page in `When user choose a brand`.